# Who is responsible for updating the Maven repository for App Engine and can anyone else do it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-2, maven, pom.xml

I have this declaration in my `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-repo</id>
        <name>jboss repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

So, when I try to update my project to use the latest version of the Google App Engine SDK (1.5.3), I get this error message from Maven on the command line:

```
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.5.3/appengine-api-1
.0-sdk-1.5.3.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.5.3' in repository jboss-repo (https://repository.jbo
ss.org/nexus/content/groups/public)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.5.3/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.3.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.5.3' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/ma
ven2)
```

This seems to mean that the repository has not been updated with the latest version of the App Engine SDK.

So, is it possible for anyone to update this public repository and add the latest version?

Or is it just a matter of having to wait for whoever is responsible for doing so to get around to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is responsible for getting the JAR's into the central maven repository and that usually happens within a few days of the release of a new version. The JBoss repository is not necessary for the GAE artifacts.

Last I heard [here](http://groups.google.com/group/maven-gae-plugin/browse_thread/thread/34e1e3772604ad75) from David Chandler (Google) was that there was an issue with the original 1.5.3 JAR so it was taking some extra time to get them into central.

Per David:

> Not in Central yet. There was a problem found with the 1.5.3 Java SDK
>   so I'm  waiting for the final version to push to Central.

Comment: Here's the latest: http://groups.google.com/group/maven-gae-plugin/browse_thread/thread/727a7d32b96d8efe

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the JBoss repo for GAE? GAE artifacts are in central, and if anything, I'd expect them to show up in the [oss.sonatype.org Nexus server](http://oss.sonatype.org), but neither of those have 1.5.3 yet either.

Comment: I misunderstood something. I'm using the JBoss repo for Hibernate Validator and sontatype for GAE. Sorry I don't have the privilege yet to give you an upvote but your answer was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What artifacts are you trying to get?

You can't download the sdk directly from maven. You have to download the individual sdk dependencies, i.e. appengine-tools, appengine-api and appengine-local-runtime-shared.

Thanks

Comment: That is not true. The GAE artifacts are in the central maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to [remind the SDK developers](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) to post the latest version to Maven Central - except [they already have been reminded](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5621&q=maven&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).

As noted earlier, don't expect anyone else to post to JBoss's repo.

Comment: Your second link is very interesting. Sorry I can't vote you up.

Comment: @Saffrey, true, but you can star the issue over at google code!